# EF Core with Angular - query fast in SQL Profiler, slow in practice

Tags: sql, sql-server, angular, linq, ef-core-3.1

I have a not so big db - 6 tables, up to 400 records each, 4 joins. My problem is that queries are slow when in practice. It used to take 30 secs, it randomly dropped to 2 sec, and back again, etc. when reading almost the whole db, then it seemed to stay at 2sec. Some were saying my PC has not enough RAM. So I introduced paging with 10 record a page, and it's still more than 2 sec on the frontend, although SQL Profiler says it's done in 10-20ms. Without includes with 10 records stays 2sec.

LINQ:

```
        var events = await eventRepository
            .GetAllWith()
            .Skip(page * 10)
            .Take(10)
            .Include(e => e.Sport)
            .Include(e => e.League)
            .Include(e => e.Markets)
                .ThenInclude(m => m.Results)
            .ToListAsync();
```

Here's the query that runs:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[AwayTeam], [t].[Date], [t].[HomeTeam], [t].[LeagueId], [t].[Outcome], [t].[SportId], [s].[Id], [s].[Name], [l].[Id], [l].[Name], [l].[SportId], [t0].[Id], [t0].[EventId], [t0].[id0], [t0].[MarketId], [t0].[name], [t0].[odds], [t0].[sourceName]
FROM (
    SELECT [e].[Id], [e].[AwayTeam], [e].[Date], [e].[HomeTeam], [e].[LeagueId], [e].[Outcome], [e].[SportId]
    FROM [Event] AS [e]
    ORDER BY (SELECT 1)
    OFFSET @__p_0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @__p_1 ROWS ONLY
) AS [t]
INNER JOIN [Sport] AS [s] ON [t].[SportId] = [s].[Id]
INNER JOIN [League] AS [l] ON [t].[LeagueId] = [l].[Id]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [m].[Id], [m].[EventId], [r].[id] AS [id0], [r].[MarketId], [r].[name], [r].[odds], [r].[sourceName]
    FROM [Market] AS [m]
    LEFT JOIN [ResultEntity] AS [r] ON [m].[Id] = [r].[MarketId]
) AS [t0] ON [t].[Id] = [t0].[EventId]
ORDER BY [t].[Id], [s].[Id], [l].[Id], [t0].[Id], [t0].[id0]',N'@__p_0 int,@__p_1 int',@__p_0=0,@__p_1=10
```

I tried to change nvarchars to varchars, eliminate nullable equality checks, but it didn't solve my problem. How could I solve it?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (MS SQL Server perhaps?)

Comment: SQL Express (SQL Server 14)

Comment: If your database profiler says it takes 20ms tops, then your next step is to figure out where all that time is lost. Profile your application. Maybe with really easy printouts. If it is in the 30 seconds range, you don't need sophisticated tools. Slap in a few prints and you should see where the time is spent.

Comment: It seems to be a problem related to proxying with Angular. Without it, the first query takes 3 sec and the followings about 100ms.

Comment: Running a query for the first time in SQL is sometimes slow, because SQL constructs and caches something called query execution plan, which will be used the next time you run your query. I'm not sure that this is your problem though.